# dynamic layouts in Angular is Introducing a special character into the UI

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, dynamic

Observations:

- when I type into the boxes, those symbols disappear.
- when I type into the boxes and remove the typed text, it no longer visible
- when I type invalid text into the box , the symbol turns red.

Here is the code: (code is big, had to use pastebin,sorry)
 http://pastebin.com/s7w8Sx2h

Here is the screenshot of the problem: 
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/OlekrcP.jpg]

Comment: Tip: Embed the picture in the question

Comment: it says i don't have reputation to post pictures.

Comment: from what you are saying this is an issue with CSS and validation, debug it with developer tools

Comment: I've added the image for you

Comment: I understand that your code is very long, but please add relevant sections of it to the question

Comment: @maurycy Thank you very much, and i did try to debug using developer tools, i cant focus on that character, it does not exist in the DOM, i think its an Angular ng-Form issue(i may be wrong)

Comment: If you can recreate it on plunker that would be great